# Adding items to the Console Menu

Tags: menu, console, wndproc

I added menu items to the console menu in C# and hooked them to  WndProc using SetWindowLongPtr(consoleWindow, GWL_WNDPROC, Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(new WndProcDelegate(WndProc))), but my WndProc never gets executed. What am I missing?